# How do I implement asteriods ship movement?

Tags: opengl, c++

```
void Draw_Ship()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glTranslatef(0.0f, up, 0.0f);

    draw_ship();

    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glRotatef(angle_two, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    draw_ship_two();

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I am working on an asteroids clone using c++ and opengl, I want my space ship to rotate around an point and to follow its nose.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to keep around a value that represents the current rotation of the ship. Let's call it `currentRotation`. When the user presses the left or right arrow keys (or whatever keys you're using for rotate left and rotate right), you need to update the `currentRotation` by some amount. The amount will probably be based on how frequently you draw.

Once you know the orientation you want for a given frame, you can perform ship movement by doing the following. Assume the `anchorPoint` is the point in the ship's local coordinate space that you want it to rotate around. Usually this would be the center of the ship.

```
glTranslatef(-anchor.x, -anchor.y, 0.0);
glRotatef(currentRotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(anchor.x, anchor.y, 0.0);
```

If you then want to move it forward in the direction it's facing, you need to calculate the vector for that direction, and then multiply it by the distance you want to travel:

```
direction.x = cos(degreesToRadians(currentRotation)) * distance;
direction.y = sin(degreesToRadians(currentRotation)) * distance;
```

You can now translate it further by using the above vector:

```
glTranslatef(direction.x, direction.y, 0.0);
```